# Magento 2 mini cart delete not works

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Magento 2 mini cart delete not works

[image]

Comment: which error you have facing?

Comment: when i click a delete button item would not removed in min cart

Comment: check exception log what is error generate

Comment: exception log is empty

Comment: exception log is empty

Comment: check your website is developer mode?

Comment: Please check console log in the browser. Might you get some js error.

Comment: i m get no error in console

Comment: Have you tried static-content:deploy?